# how to empty the password field after calling auto generated function (after click the save button )

Tags: forms, function, passwords, blazor, blazor-server-side

> Actually, this auto generated password code works fine . But i'm
> calling this same function in two different places . one in "sign up" and in  "  Reset Password " option.
> After entering the password field(using the auto generated password)
> in the sign up .When i tried to reset the password field, the password
> field is filled with the previously entered password. how to solve
> this one. i want to clear the password everytime i "sign up" a nd
> reset the password.

```
@code
{
    public void GetRandomPassword()
            {
                Password = string.Empty;
                char[] chars = "$%#@!*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890?;:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ^&".ToCharArray();
                Password = string.Empty;
                Random random = new Random();
        
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    int x = random.Next(1, chars.Length);
                    if (!Password.Contains(chars.GetValue(x).ToString()))
                        Password += chars.GetValue(x);
                    else
                        i--;
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the razor component calling your code ? I don't understand the problem for the moment. Regards

Comment: thank for ur time to ask my issue again its fixed now.  My problem was the password field was not cleared wenever i call this function.i was calling that in 2 different places. Actually i put the Password= string.Empty in the beginning actually it should be put after  the function is called .its just a placing issue. Thank you again  for ur time and consideration.i really appreciate.